# Store Checkbox value to array list

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

How do I store the value of a checked checkbox to an array list and display it in a list./..say Checkbox1 = "Apple"......so far I have this

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
    if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
        //my problem is below here: I can't seem to add the value of it not the id and store it in list

        pubsList.add(pub3);
        pub3=Integer.toString(checkBox1.getSelectedItem());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 For only one check box e.g.selectAll you can have this---

selectAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
         {

           if ( isChecked )
              {
                Log.e(TAG, "Select all Checkbox enabled");
                String ad=(String) selectAll.getText();//get text of selectAll checkbox
                SelectionList.add(ad);//add above text to list of strings

               }
                      if(! isChecked)
                      {
                         //do something if required
                      }

                  }


              });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i used this instead to condense `add(checkBox4.getText().toString());`